# yarn-site.xml vs. yarn-default.xml in YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn

What is the difference between yarn-site.xml vs. yarn-default.xml in YARN? It looks like yarn-default.xml is deprecated in Hadoop 2.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all of Hadoop, *-default.xml files mostly serve as the documentation for the default values. Default values are all hard-coded anyways into the source. *-site.xml files represent any site specific changes and override the defaults specified in *-default.xml files.

To the specific question, yarn-default.xml and yarn-site.xml are both read by Hadoop YARN daemons, with yarn-default.xml denoting the defaults and yarn-site.xml representing custom configuration values that override those in yarn-default.xml.